# Is it possible to serialize and store cached data in secondary memory ie. in some folder/File system in some form on nodes in Hazelcast?

Tags: hazelcast

I am planning to cache application data using Hazelcast.
Wanted to know is there a way to serialize and store cached data into secondary memory of the nodes?

Basically I want to serialize and store cached data in some folder on node. So that it would be possible to restore web session in worst case when both of my nodes die.

Comment: you can - you need to implement the store load functionality.  Why don't you use a database of some sort for this as opposed to writing to files yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement the store load functionality (add the store load implementation class name in the config XML file for Hazelcast), the store load implementation will get invoked for any map put/delete operations.  You can use load all at application bootup time while load will get used in case the data is not in the cache (in which case it will attempt to fetch the data form the backend implementation).  I would suggest that you use a database (any kind) as opposed to rolling out your own file based implementation.

**Test map XML File info:**

```
<map name="testMap">     
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy> 
        <max-size policy="cluster_wide_map_size">0</max-size>
        <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
        <merge-policy>hz.ADD_NEW_ENTRY</merge-policy>
<!-- MapStore-Load-->
<map-store enabled="true">
<class-name>models.test.StoreLoadTestMap</class-name>
<write-delay-seconds>0</write-delay-seconds> 
</map-store>
    </map>
```

In your implementation class, you need to provide implementation for store, storeAll, load, loadAll, loadAllKeys, delete, deleteAll.

Comment: Can you please share some more information or links on using store load functionality to store cached web session data into File system. My application itself doesn't have database, so I am not willing to have database just for storing cached web session.

Comment: you have to persist data somewhere - file or DB.  Writing to file will probably be less reliable and take longer development time (and depending on your app, you can go with a lightweight DB if needed).  Store load implementations are available on hazelcast docs.  You need to specify class name in your hazelcast xml file and actually implement all the callbacks in that class (sepcified in the xml file)

Comment: That's really great information for beginner like me.. I tried one POC to store it in file. It worked well. But I had to add class file in hazelcast node for serializing and storing "Student" object in my POC. So my question is- Is it possible not to have class's on nodes because I want to avoid updating code on every node i.e. on every server where my nodes are present just for every change in class definition like if new field added in Student or so..?

Comment: You implement your class - make it serializable - custom or default, specify the map which contains relevant objects in hazelcast xml file and specify the replication factor - hazelcast will take care of distributing the data for the map (distribution and replication are different).  When you need access to the map, you use hazelcast to retrieve it (hazelcast will retrieve it from whichever node(s) contains the map data) - if you really must, you can use local cache though I would suggest you avoid that at this juncture as you're going to complicate your implementation

Comment: Ali I think I confused you, let me re-frame my question. Let say my application(client app) does have Student entity and I have node configured. Then in this case for persisting state on Files system/DB I have to have Student.class on node as well. And I don't want to have or update class on each modification in Student on node side. Is it possible?

Comment: not sure if I followed what you said. Let's say you have a class Student.  You create an object st1. You store that in Hazelcast Map.  If you need to update the object, you need to retrieve the object from the map and then store it again into the Hazelcast map (essentially updating the map).  I am assuming you would want to update the file with the updated info as well at that point (for which you can use the store-load implementation). If you do not wish to, you can keep a boolean in the student class to track whether you wish to update the file or not (or an external tracker to do the same).

Comment: also, when data is distributed, there is always an owner node for data i.e. if one node gets 20% of the data, that node becomes primary for the data and will take care of store-load - its best if you do not write to local file - its not a good option may reasons (use a database of some sort).  If the answer provided is not correct, good luck - if it is, mark it as corrected.